# Why is my interaction significance different depending on the model?

Tags: r, regression, anova

In this minimal reproducible example, there is an outcome variable and two predictors (age and sex).

```
outcome <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5,
             5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9)

sex <- c("M","M","M","M","F","M","F","F","M","M",
         "F","F","F","F","M","M","F","F","F","F")

age <- c("C","C","C","A","C","C","C","C","C","A",
         "C","C","A","C","C","C","C","A","A","A")

dt <- data.frame(outcome = o, sex = as.factor(s), age = as.factor(a))
```

The boxplot suggests there is an interaction:

[image: The boxplot suggests there is an interaction]

When I check the interaction as part of a model I get a different statistical significance than when I check the interaction alone.

```
anova(lm(outcome ~ sex + age + sex:age, dt))

anova(lm(outcome ~ sex:age, dt))
```

The first gives a p-value of 0.187499 for the interaction term, while the second a p-value of 0.007738.

Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tests are making different comparisons.  In general, the tests in `anova()` compare the full model to the model with that term left out.  (Edited to add:  though things are more complicated when interactions are involved; the main effect tests being an example of that.)  In the first case, the full model is

```
outcome ~ sex + age + sex:age
```

and leaving out `sex:age` gives

```
outcome ~ sex + age
```

the main effects model.  So in that case you are really testing the interaction, and it is not significant:  in the plot, it looks like `C` and `M` both give lower values than the other level (`A` and `F` respectively).

In the second case, the full model is

```
outcome ~ sex:age
```

Here `sex:age` is a 4 level factor containing all combinations of the factor levels.  Leaving it out gives

```
outcome ~ 1
```

So in this case the test is for any kind of difference at all among the groups, and there's obviously something going on, so it comes out significant.

Comment: Let me see if I understand:  in sex + age +sex:age, the interaction term is not significant on its own because the other predictors have stronger effects, but sex:age alone is significant because it includes the sex and age factors?

Comment: I'd word it differently, but you're basically right.  I find it more helpful to think of what is being tested: a model with a separate effect for each of the four groups is the full model in both cases, but the comparison model is a main effects model in the first case, and a model saying all observations are the same in the second case.

Comment: Thanks I've marked it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why they are different is that in one model you included the main effects and the other model you only included the interaction term. This will yield different p-values.

These two models would be the same:

```
anova(lm(outcome ~ sex + age + sex:age, dt))

anova(lm(outcome ~ sex*age, dt))
```

Note the `*` notation in the model means it includes the main effects and the interaction and the `:` only means the interaction term.

Comment: this is a good start, but could use more detail ...

Comment: The model with formula `outcome ~ sex:age` includes all three terms taken as a single 3 df term representing all 4 levels of the interaction term.  It's not the same as `sex:age` in the `sex*age` or `sex + age + sex:age` model, where it only represents the part that is independent of the main effects.

Comment: Yes I am asking why including the extra terms gives a different p-value compared to the interaction alone. Thanks.

Comment: I explain that in my answer.